# How can I improve sparklyr read csv performance?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I think reading in CSV files are excruciatingly slow using `sparklyr`. See MVE

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

conf <- spark_config()
conf$spark.executor.memory <- "60GB"
conf$spark.memory.fraction <- 0.9
conf$spark.executor.cores <- 6
conf$spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled <- "false"
sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(master = "local", config = conf)

library(data.table)

fwrite(data.table(
  id1 = sample(sprintf("id%03d",1:K), N, TRUE),      # large groups (char)
  id2 = sample(sprintf("id%03d",1:K), N, TRUE),      # large groups (char)
  id3 = sample(sprintf("id%010d",1:(N/K)), N, TRUE), # small groups (char)
  id4 = sample(K, N, TRUE),                          # large groups (int)
  id5 = sample(K, N, TRUE),                          # large groups (int)
  id6 = sample(N/K, N, TRUE),                        # small groups (int)
  v1 =  sample(5, N, TRUE),                          # int in range [1,5]
  v2 =  sample(5, N, TRUE),                          # int in range [1,5]
  v3 =  sample(round(runif(100,max=100),4), N, TRUE) # numeric e.g. 23.5749
), "a.csv")

system.time(sparklyr::spark_read_csv(sc, "a", "a.csv"))
```

I have already tried to increase the level of RAM available to Spark but the reading speed is too slow at 500 seconds! This is crazily slow compared to `data.table::fread`.

Is there anyway to configure Spark so that it's faster?

Comment: the file is stored locally? what happens if you `fread` the CSV & then parallelize it? is your spark context local? just confirming you really have 60Gb local memory...

Comment: yes everything is local on my computer.  I am trying to improve local mode performance

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/h2oai/db-benchmark/blob/master/spark/groupby-spark.py) for the code used in the [dbbenchmark](https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/)... have you used `spark.read.csv` as well?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three problems here:

- `local` mode is not distributed or even parallel. It will just use a single local thread. If you have only one node at your disposal at least try to increase the number of available threads (possibly exceeding the number of available cores).

  In general a single JVM path is not he best approach, especially with largish memory. Even if you don't have multiple nodes at your disposal you can use pseudo-distrubuted with standalone cluster and collocated master and worker.
- You don't provide schema for the reader, and require schema inference (default value of `infer_schema` argument). If you want to avoid this overhead you should [provide a schema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43003185/6910411).
- You eagerly cache data (default value of `memory` argument), which is both [expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52130402/6910411) and seldom useful.

Additionally:

- Such high value of `spark.memory.fraction` is likely to drive garbage collector crazy filling old gen. Be sure to check GC times, and if there are unusually high, reduce `spark.memory.fraction` below default (0.6), not increase.

Finally:

- Lower your expectations. Spark [will be very slow compared to optimized, in-core, native library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48815341/6910411).